# SMTP error with CodeIgniter and gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I am using outlook.com with custom domain (eg, nono@forexample.com)

I am using code igniter Email library

Openssl is enabled

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?
I have tried many solutions by others' example. it doesn't work.
i have check with service provider, they doesn't block the port

**the config (at config/email.php)**

```
$config['protocol']='smtp';
$config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port']='587';
$config['smtp_timeout']='30';
$config['smtp_user']='thenameidontknow@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']='password';
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['newline']='\r\n';
```

**Here is how i send the email (at controller/test.php)**

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('thenameidontknow@gmail.com', 'my name');
$this->email->to('lalalala@live.com');
$this->email->subject('test title or subject');
$this->email->message('the content');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

**and i got such long error message**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: Failed to enable crypto

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:587 (Unknown error)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:
......
```

Comment: Remove `ssl://` from the host. You define security methods separately.

Comment: @FruityP, thanks i got such error: Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. er3sm54076020pbb.40 - gsmtp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @SamV points out in a comment, the problem is this lines on `system/libraries/Email`:

```
$ssl = ($this->smtp_crypto === 'ssl') ? 'ssl://' : '';

$this->_smtp_connect = fsockopen($ssl.$this->smtp_host,
                        $this->smtp_port,
                        $errno,
                        $errstr,
                        $this->smtp_timeout);
```

If you remove the `ssl://` from the smtp_host and you leave it as:

```
$config['smtp_host']='smtp.googlemail.com';
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $config['smtp_port']='465';
```

Comment: port 465 is not opened

Comment: Then try this 
$config['smtp_host']='tls://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port']='587';

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$config = Array(
   'protocol' => 'smtp',
   'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
   'smtp_port' => 465,
   'smtp_user' => 'user', //without @gmail.com
   'smtp_pass' => 'pass'
 );
$this->load->library('email',$config);
```

**Make sure you dont use the @gmail.com for smtp_user**

Comment: 'smtp_user' => 'user', //without [at]gmail.com......I think [at]gmail.com is required.

Comment: I've used that exact code with the @gmail and it worked. Maybe it works both ways with gmail. I wanted to suggest it just in case

Comment: It works both ways. Just as when you login to gmail, you can use either with or without the @gmail.com.